# Pass Javascript Object to PHP JSON decode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

First, I realize there are a lot of other similar posts. I have read through many, and I have still not been able to this it to work. That being said.....I have a  2 dimensional javascript object that is created dynamically. I am trying to pass it to PHP so I can save insert it into a MySQL table. It looks like the easiest way to do this is with an Ajax post. 
Here is my javascript:

```
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(TableData);

               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    data: jsonString, 

                    success: function(){
                        alert("OK");
                    } 
                });
```

I always get the success alert so I don't think the problem is there.
Here is my PHP file.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "SME";
$password = "mypass";
$db = "p3";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if (!$conn) {

         die("Could not connect to database");
        } else echo "hey hey";


$data = json_decode("jsonString");


     print $data;

 ?>
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Both of the files are in the same folder so I don't think it's a URL problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$data = json_decode($_POST);`

Comment: you cant `echo / print` an array ( at least in a meaningful way) try `print_r()`, `var_dump()` or `var_export()` next time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in my PHP code. Here's the answer.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['denied'], true);
```

I was then able to insert into my MySQL table like this:

```
foreach($data as $user) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO deniedusers (firstname, lastname, username, email, password) values ('".$user['fname']."', '".$user['lname']."', '".$user['uname']."', '".$user['email']."', '".$user['password']."')";
```

I appreciate everyone's answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem. In order to access the what you're passing on, you need to get it from the `$_POST` variable which is an array. You can iterate over that array to get what you need and insert it in to your database after doing '$data = json_decode($_POST);`

Notice that your `type` in AJAX is `post` this is the same as the form method. It might also help in your ajax if you added `dataType: "json" to your parameters.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit.php',
                data: jsonString,
                dataType: 'json'

                success: function(){
                    alert("OK");
                }
```

Comment: I have made your suggested changes and it appears that my data is null. I used var_dump($data) and there is nothing in there. The odd thing is that when I look at my array in the debugger, it appears to be filled. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `var_dump($_POST)`? What does that show?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` shows `array(0) { }`. I checked the value of my JSON.stringify variable and it has the appropriate values. One odd thing is that when I have my `dataType: 'JSON'` I don't get my success alert.

Comment: Ok, have you checked the console log when you try to post? It doesn't seem that the data is ever making it to your PHP page.

Comment: I used `console.log(jsonString);` and it shows my array values and I get my success alert. I am not sure of a way to check if it did indeed go to my submit page other than checking the console there as well or using `var_dump()`.

Comment: Can you post the results of jsonString?

Comment: Here is jsonString `[{"fname":"Evan","lname":"Lalo","uname":"elalo","email":"lalo","deny":"","approve":"","info":""},{"fname":"Using","lname":"User","uname":"User","email":"user@steelcase.com","deny":"","approve":"","info":""}]` Here is the value of `tableData` before I stringify. `[Object, Object]`

Comment: If you comment everything else out on submit.php and just do `var_dump($_POST)` do you get anything?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. Side note; thanks for looking at this. I am thoroughly stumped.

Comment: Instead of a `var_dump($_POST)`, try `var_dump($_REQUEST)`. Just make sure there's nothing else on that submit.php file.

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST)` shows nothing as well. If it helps, this is the link I was using [link](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/store-html-table-data-to-javascript-array#step3). I stopped at step three which converts my array into an object. The step after that does not work for some reason.

Comment: Here's another crazy idea for you. Try this:

`var final_data = JSON.stringify({postdata:data});`

I want to see if that wraps it properly as just a string of data belonging to a single post variable. And then use ajax to send `final_data` instead of data.

And of course to test this, just do `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see if it worked. If that works, then try `var_dump($_POST)` and if that works, the rest should be easy.

Comment: When I `console.log(final_data)` all of the data is there and again, it shows as null in my submit.php file. This makes me think the problem is in my Ajax post. I'm going to keep trying. I appreciate you efforts.

Comment: you're welcome. I don't think there's much left I can do.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like in your PHP you're not actually grabbing the posted data.

This is how I would recommend getting the data:

```
<?php
    // Check if the posted value is not empty
    if (!empty($_POST('jsonString')) {
        $jsonData = json_decode($_POST('jsonString'));
    }
?>
```

Then you can do what you need to do with the $jsonData.